# Does the rebbetzin (rabbi's wife) have a special seat in the ezras nashim (women's side of the synagogue)?

Tags: synagogue, women, history

Usually the rabbi gets a special seat.  I'd seen the [Pnei Yehoshua's contract in Berlin 200+ years ago](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=361&st=%u05EA%u05E9%u05E8%u05D9) specify a special seat for his wife as well, but is anyone aware of shuls today that do that?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the Shuls I have been to (Chasidish) designate a special seat for the Rebetzin.

Comment: Were these places chasidish?  Yeshivish?  MO?  American?  Israeli?  Any kind of trend you can describe?

Comment: I've never seen a shul more right than MO that has the assigned seat.  I have seen one MO shul that does.

Comment: The Chabad shul in 770 had a seat for the Rebbetzin; I guess people (maybe only those who don't know anything) sit there now. This page https://www.kof-k.org/articles/021909100259Doc13.pdf suggests that women, too, are supposed to have a fixed place for davening; a fortiori one woul think it should apply to the rebbetzin.

Answer (score 2):

In Boston, the seat were the Bostoner Rebbitzin sat before she past away is not used by anyone. I think there is a sign telling people not to sit there.

Comment: Was the sign there during her lifetime as well?

Comment: I don't know. I wasn't there beforehand. Sorry!